# Gnome-Software running in background and consuming RAM

Tags: 22.10, gnome-software, background-process

Why does this newfangled Gnome-Software have to consume 300mb of my precious RAM in the background? I remember when an previous computer of mine only had 300mb of RAM total, and now this one program is using that much on its own in the background, what can I do ?

Best regards Charles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to prevent the software from autostarting at login.

- Remove the link in `~/snap/snap-store/current/.config/autostart/`

Another option is to Quit the application. (Not close the window, that doesn't Quit the application)

Comment: will that also stop snap notifications that drive many of us nuts? I do not mind manually updating snaps  when I feel the urge?

Comment: @pierrely it will stop reminders for the snap store, since that application won't be running. It won't prevent reminders from other applications that you have open but should be closed and refreshed.

Comment: imagine having in a couple of years time 100 snap apps and they ALL do a regular popup ... whinge mode.